# javascript make form vanish when submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is I have a form on my website for people to submit their email address.  I'm trying to make it so it vanishes after they enter it to stop people entering multiple emails.

Is their a way to make the form input box and submit button vanish after the button has been clicked?

Comment: What if user has JS disabled? This issue is less common these days, but it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but would do the trick.

```
<form onsubmit="this.style.display='none';">
```

With a little more JS (probably using jQuery / Mootools or the like) you could make the vanishing a bit less harsh.